# WebElement xpath changes based on user who has logged in

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a web driver script which simulates a user login behavior. once the user has logged in, the user is supposed to click on a few tabs. My problem is that the number of tabs differ based on user and therefore the xpath of the tab also changes. there is no ID or other reliable thing that i can use. i have provided both the xpath below. please let me know how can i find this webelement?

```
XPATH1: "//*[@id=\"leftNavBarId\"]/ul/li[3]/div[1]/span[2]"
XPATH2: "//*[@id=\"leftNavBarId\"]/ul/li[4]/div[1]/span[2]"
```

The HTML of the page is given below. I am trying to click on 'Admin' tab but its xpath changes based on logged in user. The diff between the two xpaths is li[3] and li[4]. Is there a way to ignore this part?

```
<li ng-repeat="menu in workingNavCopy" ng-class="{open : menu.$subMenuOpen, 'sub-menu-not-present':!menu.$subMenuPresent}" class="ng-scope open">
  <div ng-click="select(menu,menu)" ng-class="{active: isActive(menu)}">  
    <span>
      <i class="icon-ico_settings1_lg"></i>
    </span>
    <span class="ng-binding">**Admin**</span>
  </div>
  <div ng-show="menu.$subMenuPresent">
      <ul class="secondaryMenu">
         <!-- ngRepeat: subMenu in menu.subMenu -->
         <li ng-repeat="subMenu in menu.subMenu" class="ng-scope">
            <div ng-click="select(subMenu,menu)" ng-class="{active: isActive(subMenu)}"> <span class="ng-binding">abc</span> </div>
         </li>
         <!-- end ngRepeat: subMenu in menu.subMenu -->
         <li ng-repeat="subMenu in menu.subMenu" class="ng-scope">
            <div ng-click="select(subMenu,menu)" ng-class="{active: isActive(subMenu)}"> <span class="ng-binding">pqr</span> </div>
         </li>
         <!-- end ngRepeat: subMenu in menu.subMenu -->
         <li ng-repeat="subMenu in menu.subMenu" class="ng-scope">
            <div ng-click="select(subMenu,menu)" ng-class="{active: isActive(subMenu)}"> <span class="ng-binding">xyz</span> </div>
         </li>
         <!-- end ngRepeat: subMenu in menu.subMenu -->
         <li ng-repeat="subMenu in menu.subMenu" class="ng-scope">
            <div ng-click="select(subMenu,menu)" ng-class="{active: isActive(subMenu)}"> <span class="ng-binding">mno</span> </div>
         </li>
         <!-- end ngRepeat: subMenu in menu.subMenu --> 
      </ul>
   </div>
    </li>
```

Comment: And how can we help without the html?

Comment: @Guy , i have added the html. please take a look and let me know if something can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search directly for element with `Admin` text

```
"//span[contains(., 'Admin')]"
or
"//*[contains(., 'Admin')]"
```

If it isn't unique enough search for such element with ancestor with `id=leftNavBarId`

```
"//*[@id='leftNavBarId']//span[contains(., 'Admin')]"
```

Comment: Your solution worked for me. i tried the first one you recommended and it worked like a charm. Thanks  a lot. Will try the second option later. Too lazy to try the ancestor one... :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following `xpath` for the same as you having trouble with `<li>` tag so you can start from there and find the element based on text-

```
.//li/div/span[text()='Admin']

//or

.//li/div/span[normalize-space()='Admin']
```

Comment: Your solution also works. Thanks a lot. But I can mark only one as the right answer... :(

Answer (score 0):

First you can find the tab that contains "Admin" using this:

```
IwebElement adminTab= driver.FindElement(By.XPath(string.Format("//div[@id='leftNavBarId']/ul/li[contains(text(),'admin')]")));
```

Then work with adminTab.

Comment: This one did not work for me for some reason. The element did not get detected. Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below mentioned `xpath`

```
//span[@class='ng-binding'][text()= 'Admin']
```

**Explanation of xpath:-** Use `class` attribute and `text` method of `<span>` tag.

Comment: Does my explanation of code `helped` you? if it does then please mark this answer as `Accepted`